# How to remove sign column after doing :grep in vim

Tags: vim

I'm not sure exactly what is adding the '>>' to the sign column, but it appears to be there for anything from the quickfix window. Is there a way to clear the whole column without doing a funky :grep search (for soifjseofseogh for example).

Answer (score 4):

The fastest way is probably to do:

```
:sign unplace *
```

You could set this up as a user defined :-command, or a mapping. For example, to make "`\u`" trigger the command:

```
:nmap <silent> <leader>u :sign unplace *<CR>
```

However, what you describe is not default Vim behavior. You probably have a plugin that creates the signs whenever the Quickfix stuff is triggered.  Take a look at the output of "`:scriptnames`" and see if you can spot something that looks related.

Comment: amazing, many plugins use signs, like python-mode for linting, `:sign unplace *` is the way to clear them. Leaving this note for people to find

Answer (score 1):

In Vim 8, you can now also do `:set scl=no` to hide the sign column forever (thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46636973/5951320) on Stack Overflow for pointing this out).